# Javascript event for mobile browser re-launch or device wake

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile

Morning all, I'm looking for some kind of Javascript event I can use to detect when a mobile browser window regains focus, after either a user closes/minimizes their browser (to go back to a home screen/different app), or if the device resumes from sleep (either the user powering it off, or it going to sleep after a screen timeout).

I'd like to be able to find a single event that works for everything, but I know that's unlikely! The `pageshow` event works for iOS devices, but it's rather sketchy for use with everything else. I've tried `focus` and `DOMActivate` but neither of them seem to have the desired effect.

The page may not always have form elements on it, and I don't really want the user to have to touch the page again to trigger the event.

The requirement for such an event is caused by our code periodically checking for new content by making XHR requests. These are never sent when the browser is asleep, so we never get new content to restart the timeouts.

Thanks for any help you guys may be able to provide!

Answer (score 19):

We had a similar issue and solved it something like this:

```
var lastSync = 0;
var syncInterval = 60000; //sync every minute

function syncPage() {
  lastSync = new Date().getTime(); //set last sync to be now
  updatePage(); //do your stuff
}

setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  if ((now - lastSync) > syncInterval ) {
    syncPage();
  }
}, 5000); //check every 5 seconds whether a minute has passed since last sync
```

This way you would sync every minute if your page is active, and if you put your browser in idle mode for over a minute, at most 5 seconds will pass before you sync upon opening the browser again. Short intervals might drain the battery more than you would like, so keep that in mind when adapting the timings to you needs.

Comment: smart. if it has been asleep, the lastSync would be outdated and then you refresh or asked to be pushed against (if using websockets) ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the answer is 'yes' :)

you do whatever you need to where I call my updatePage() function. In my case, I ask the server for a state and update the client accordingly. If they are still in the same state, the update does nothing.

Comment: 2019 update: if you stumble on this (excellent, and still working) answer like I did, you can also check out the recent [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) which worked for me in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome on iOS 12.4 (*edit: formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Better than an interval would be to add a window blur listener and a window focus listener.  On blur, record current time.  On focus, validate you are still logged in / sync'd / whatever you need to do.

Basically exactly the same thing but it runs only when necessary rather than slowing your entire page down with an interval.

**Update**

```
var $window = $(window),
  $window.__INACTIVITY_THRESHOLD = 60000;

$window.add(document.body);  //necessary for mobile browsers

$window.declareActivity = function () { $window.__lastEvent = new Date(); };

$window.blur($window.declareActivity);
$window.focus(function(){
  var diff = (new Date()) - $window.__lastEvent;
  if (diff > $window.__INACTIVITY_THRESHOLD) { 
     $window.trigger("inactivity"); 
  }
});

$window.on("inactivity", "", null, function () {
  //your inactivity code
});
```

Though that blur event seems sketchy if the phone is powering off and I don't know that I would trust it in all circumstances / mobile devices.  So I'd probably throw in something like this:

```
$(document.body).on("click scroll keyup", "", null, $window.declareActivity);
```

so that my inactivity timer works for when the user just walks away as well.  Depending on your site, you may want to adjust that exact event list - or simply throw in a $window.declareActivity(); into your existing scripts that respond to user inputs.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code that illustrates your solution?