# Reload web page when mobile device wakes from sleep

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax

I have created a countdown clock that works with Javascript/HTML/PHP/MySQL.

As soon as you click "Start Countdown", the epoch time is stored in the database and the countdown starts.

When you reload the page, it goes to the database, fetches the epoch time the countdown started, compares it with the time the page was reloaded and calculates the remaining time. Then the JS kicks in and continues the countdown correctly without starting from the start. For example:

I set the countdown time to 100 seconds.

I click: Start countdown

100, 99, 98, 97, 96...

I reload the page (lets say it takes 2 seconds to load)

It continues counting down from where it should be: 94, 93, 92, 91 ... 0

This works perfectly on every web browser (Yes, even Internet Explorer), but i have a problem with mobile devices: When a mobile device sleeps the countdown stops (i assume that its like closing the browser on a PC), and when i wake it up it continues counting from where i left it instead from where i left it minus the total seconds the device was sleeping.

My question is: Is there an event in JavaScript/Jquery that will fire as soon as a mobile device wakes up?

Checking online i found this : [Javascript event for mobile browser re-launch or device wake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798516/javascript-event-for-mobile-browser-re-launch-or-device-wake)

Its a nice solution but it will contact the server every X seconds (in this case 5 seconds) when the user is at the page. This will cause a lot of traffic at the page and i want to prevent it. [Please correct me if i am wrong].

Any solution will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set the remaining time.  Set the actual time and let JavaScript calculate the remaining time at each interval and your problem is solved.

Comment: I havent have any time to test it but i think you may be right!! I will try it and let you know! Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe i wrote it wrong.. The calculations are done in JS.. I changed the calculation methods but still nothing.  I think that as soon as the mobile device sleeps, the JS stops to work, saving the last values before sleeping. As soon as the device wakes, the JS kicks in , and uses these values to countdown instead of the correct one.

Comment: That should be fine. When JS kicks in it reads the date and time you set (which shouldn't have changed) and calculates the difference between it and the current time. It should do this at every interval (eg every second). The date you set never changes and the current time is always up to date on the device so there should be no way for the calculation to fail if you are performing it every second.

Comment: I will test it even further later today.. A FACT: When a desktop/laptop browser closes then the JS is not executed. But as soon as you navigate to that page again the page reloads and everything works. THE QUESTION: What happens when a mobile device sleeps? Does the JS stop to work? Also what will happen if the mobile device wake at the same webpage?

Comment: I have written an application that does exactly what you describe and I implemented it exactly the way I have described to you. I just tested it in an iPad. It counts down as expected. I turn the iPad off, wait, turn it back on and js immediately kicks back in and because I am calculating the time difference every second it recalculates where it should be an keeps going. It's rock solid and dead accurate. just implement it the way I've described. Good luck.